# I have installed SSL certificate in wordpress website, but after installing ssl images are not showing (Logo image, etc.)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, wordpress-theming, ssl-certificate

I have installed SSL certificate in wordpress website, but after installing ssl images are not showing (Logo image, etc.). Please see my website link to make it clear.
https://chakdhoom.com/

Comment: The images are referenced using `https://www.chakdhoom.com/…` - but your certificate only includes the non-www version of your domain name, `chakdhoom.com`. Check your WordPress site base address in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

this is probaly because the permalink is not changed. go to setting and then permalink. make sure it is a new link and save it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have installed SSL properly and everything is working as needed. 
This can be due to mixed content issue that happens to a lot of people.
If its only the images that is not appearing. Change the image link from the theme settings to the new https version This would fix the problem.

If you are using Free SSL from cloudare follow this tutorial and check whether you have done everything properly:
https://www.techtipshacks.com/properly-implement-cloudflare-free-ssl-wordpress.html

Or if you used Let's Encrypt Free SSL follow this guide:
https://www.techtipshacks.com/add-letsencrypt-free-ssl-wordpress.html

If you have used any other ssl, i would say installing the Really Simple SSL plugin would solve the mixed content issue including broken images.